# Mapping Excel data with id’s into InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge, microsoft-excel

Is there a way when mapping from Excel into InDesign to assign id’s to the data that is being mapped? For instance, see the image below and record id 15. If we have a column header labelled “id”, can I assign that specific set of data to id=15. This way, if data is inserted before it, the mapping based on row number is not disrupted.
[image: sample image]

If this is possible, how is it mapped into InDesign? The best way I can compare what I am thinking to is similar to an html div.

Data

I want to create sectioned data that would not be disrupted by others sections, too.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase the question? As it is, it’s not very clear what exactly it is you’re trying to do. What do you mean by “can I assign that specific set of data [which set? The data in the other columns in that row?] to id=15”? How would you assign a set of data to something that looks like setting a variable to a number? Can you try showing us how you would expect this to look in InDesign?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that will suit you but If you want to keep track of data in order to easily updates changes in the layout, I would recommend looking at a plugin like EasyCatalog. It can load Excel files, keep track of data, paginate automatically and manage updates easily…